# jquery mouseenter is not working on img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqte

I am trying to drag an image to jquery Text editor (jqte) and then resize it in the editor. As the resizing function works only in firefox. so i think to provide W and H textbox on mouseenter to change the size. but the mouseenter is not working on img element.

```
     <div class="jqte_editor" contenteditable="true"><pre style="font-family:consolas;">
      <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <img style="border-left-width: 1px; border-left-style:   solid; border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" src="http://localhost:65380/Articles/ArticleImageStore/cf82c9c8-3ea0-4c7f- 9272-7b2fd48a9eed/79825f3f-965f-4e34-ad45-3fa7430e6837.JPEG" width="64" height="64" id="img6">         
     </pre>
     <p><br></p>
     <pre style="font-family:consolas;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</pre>  <p></p>                         
     </div>
```

jquery code snippet

```
         $('.jqte_editor img').on('mouseenter', function() { 
             alert("hello");
             $(this).before("<div style='position:absolute'><input type='textbox'></input></div>"); 
         });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJm2X/ @techfoobar

Comment: Remove the `$(document).ready(...);` wrapper as jsfiddle is already executing your code on page load. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJm2X/2/

Comment: Nothing is working inside JQTE ..

Comment: Did you check the fiddle link i posted?

Comment: @techfoobar No I am not talking about the fiddle.. I am talking about the page i am working in and the JQTE. There it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wZFFJ/)

Either you did not include required `jQuery library`, this [link](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) shows how jQuery works or you did not put the event binding in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

*Adding jQuery*

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" 
               type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*Binding event in document.ready*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.jqte_editor img').on('mouseenter', function() { alert("hello"); $(this).before("<div style='position:absolute'><input type='textbox'></input></div>"); });
});
```

Comment: You missed the closing ) at the end, check the updated, http://jsfiddle.net/ZJm2X/1/

Comment: Missing the closing ) at the to close `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: Sorry i missed this on the fiddle but it is there on the page. but still not working.

Comment: Jquery is on the master page

Comment: and checking the resource the jquery link is listed there

Comment: and my other jquery related activity on the page is working fine

Comment: Check if the jQuery file exists on its expected location

Comment: I have `$.Ajax` call inside `document.ready` and that is working fine. I think without jquery that would have never worked

Comment: @adil actually I am doing drag and drop and that is the issue. can you explain this

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine : http://jsfiddle.net/ANnH2/

If you didn't wrap the code in .ready function, check that once :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.jqte_editor img').on('mouseenter', function() {
        alert("hello");
        $(this).before("<div style='position:absolute'><input type='textbox'></input></div>"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Does the jqte have anything extra that can block the functionality I need